# About innerHTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it safe to use innerHTML to make something like this:

```
newContent = "";

newContent += "<tr>";
   newContent += "<td>" + data.fullname + "</td>";
   newContent += "<td>" + data.fixedname + "</td>";
   newContent += '<td class="text-center"><button id="id_'+a+'" type="button" class="btn btn-xsmall shadow-none">Button</button></td>';
newContent += "</tr>";

document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML += newContent;
```

The data I get from ajax.

or this:

```
newContent = "<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i> Submitting ...";

document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML = newContent;
```

If not what can I do to substitute it?

I am trying to use setHTML() instead of innerHTML, but I still don't know if I can replace innerHTML with that.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? In the code you presented, variables are not defined with let or var, is that ok? The second code is syntactically bad because it is trying to describe double quotes within double quotes.

Comment: `newContent = "<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i> Submitting ...";` <-- This is syntactically invalid JavaScript: you need to escape the double-quotes used for attributes. Put `newContent = "<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw\"></i> Submitting ...";` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** safe. This opens you up to a [cross-site scripting](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) attack which can, at best, cause your page to be messed up, but at worse, allow an attacker to execute arbitrary code on your website.

In order to make it safe, you need to escape the variable content:

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe)
{
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }
```

Run your variable through this function and it should be ok to use.

Comment: To be clear, what is unsafe is only the first snippet they used, and only if they don't trust the data they fetched from AJAX. It's perfectly fine to use `innerHTML` to compose DOM from a fixed markup like in their second snippet, or even from trusted data.

Comment: @Kaiido I'd err on the safe side and escape even if you trust the source. Doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: Except if what you expect is HTML maybe?

Comment: Well yeah, if you're expecting HTML then you can't escape it like this. But that's not applicable in this case since the variable is inside an attribute.

Comment: OP is setting the content of <td>  elements, there is nothing telling us they don't expect HTML produced by their backend.

Comment: I completeyl forgot about the first 2 `<td>`s for a sec lol. But based on the context, I think it's still likely that they're not expecting HTML for those 2.

Comment: Yes, I want to get the data from ajax then show it by `<table><tbody id="myID"></tbody></table>` in the 1st case. So, I must use that unsafe function only for the data from ajax right? not the entire `"<td>" + data.fullname + "</td>"` ?

Comment: @Xelariel yes, the function should only be used on the data from the request. For example, `"<td>" + escapeHtml(data.fullname) + "</td>"`

Comment: @asportnoy All right, thank you for the response..